# Google Sheets AppScript - Insert formula based on Column Value - Stop insert of formula when the same column value is blank

Tags: google-apps-script

This link will lead you to the data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSo49Q1dH55cH9VFukCtyPSU_uIyeZ1QnzmgDDIIJNk/edit?usp=sharing

I am looking to accomplish the formulas in Column B & C with AppScript

I need the script to run only **when there is a value in Column G
**
Here is what has worked to insert the corret formula - How do I get it to stop until a new value is entered in Column G

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const tabRFQ = ss.getSheetByName('RFQ DATA ENTRY TEST');

const lastRow = tabRFQ.getDataRange().getValues().length;

const dataB = tabRFQ.getRange(3, 2, lastRow - 2, 1).getValues();
const dataC = tabRFQ.getRange(3, 3, lastRow - 2, 1).getValues();

function insertFormulaB() {
  dataB.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row[0] === '') {
      let formula = `=IF(G${i + 2}=G${i + 3},B${i + 2},(B${i + 2}+1))`;
      tabRFQ.getRange(i + 3, 2).setValue(formula);
    }
  }
  )
};

function insertFormulaB() {
  dataB.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row[0] === '') {
      let formula = `=IF(G${i + 2}=G${i + 3},C${i + 2},1))`;
      tabRFQ.getRange(i + 3, 3).setValue(formula);
    }
  }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `setValue` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4)
- I thought that in your script, both the fomulas for columns "B" and "C" can be put by one function.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RFQ DATA ENTRY");
  const values = sheet.getRange("G4:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  const { b, c } = values.reduce((o, [g], i) => {
    if (g) {
      o.b.push(`B${i + 4}`);
      o.c.push(`C${i + 4}`);
    }
    return o;
  }, { b: [], c: [] });
  sheet.getRangeList(b).setFormulaR1C1("if(R[-1]C[5]=R[0]C[5],R[-1]C[0],R[-1]C[0]+1)");
  sheet.getRangeList(c).setFormulaR1C1("if(R[-1]C[4]=R[0]C[4],R[-1]C[0]+1,1)");
}
```

- When this script is run, the formulas are put to columns "B" and "C" when the value is existing in column "G".
- And, the formulas are put using R1C1.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, from your sample Spreadsheet, the formulas are put from row 4. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)
- [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setFormulaR1C1(String))

Comment: Thank you - I think I understand what you have done.  The Formulas need to be put from row 3 - I am concerned that I don't know all the places I should change the 4 to a 3??  "In this modified script, from your sample Spreadsheet, the formulas are put from row 4. Please be careful about this."  The reason I have set it to start in B3 is so I have a constant # "5000" in B2 for the +1 function to work in B3 based on if G3=G2.

Comment: Actually - I got it to work - it is perfect!!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Kelly Carlson Thank you for replying. In your provided sample Spreadsheet, I thought that you wanted to fix the values of "B3:C3". So, in my script, the formulas are put from row 4. If the formulas are put from row 3, there is no value. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @Kelly Carlson About `Actually - I got it to work - it is perfect!! Thank you so much!!`. welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I am new to this platform - I would like to give you solved/stars but don't know how...Happy to do so!